# Request failed with status code 401 - React Unit-Testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have created a table with multiple different fields below. There are more content in the table, but I will just show the part that I have problem with.

```
 <TabPane tabId="1">
                <Form>
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="6">
                      <Label>Name</Label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="3">
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Input
                          type="text"
                          name="firstName"
                          id="firstName"
                          value={firstName}
                          className={styleProfile.profileText}
                          onChange={this.handleUserProfile}
                          placeholder="First Name"
                          invalid={!this.state.formValid.firstName}
                        />
                        <FormFeedback>First Name Can't be null</FormFeedback>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
```

When I try to write unit-test for this code. For some reason, one of them can read and find the first name field area inside the table, the other code give me an **Request failed with status code 401** error.

This is my testFile.test.js file

```
describe('Sturecture', () => {
it('should render a first name field', () => {
  expect(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/first name/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
it('should render the correct first name', () => {
  expect(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/first name/i)).toHaveValue(userProfileMock.firstName);
});
```

This is the result of the test run using. yarn test.

```
     ✕ should render a first name field (92ms)
      ✓ should render the correct first name (73ms)

  ● user profile page › Sturecture › should render a first name field

    Request failed with status code 401

      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
      at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:61:7)
      at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/create-event-accessor.js:32:32)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:318:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at XMLHttpRequestImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at fireAnEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:18:36)
      at readyStateChange (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:762:3)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:888:5)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
```

I wonder what I did wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had experienced the exact same problem. I do not know the reason yet but I was able to solve my problem by mocking axios.

In your error messages, there are errors related with axios thus I suppose that you can overcome this issue by mocking axios as below either:

```
import axios from "yourAxiosPath"

jest.mock("yourAxiosPath")
```

and in your tests, before render, you should do something like:

```
axios.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({data: {}}))
```